# R / dplyr: text in var1*var2 matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have three variables.

va1 and var2 are names, eg. of database tables.

var3 stores (in a string) the column(s) of the database tables which are necessary to join the two tables.

Without any loss of generality: Each Database table has only one colum to join with another database.

Is it possible in R/ dplyr to get a martix / tibble  where var1 are the rows, var2 are the columns and var3 is the value of the var1*var2 combination?

An example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = paste0("tab",c(seq(1:5),1,1)), 
                 var2 = paste0("tab",c(2,4,5,3,1,3,4)), 
                 var3 = letters[1:7])
```

Expected result:

```
      tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4 tab5
 tab1    -    a    f    g    -
 tab2    -    -    -    b    -
 tab3    -    -    -    -    c
 tab4    -    -    d    -    -
 tab5    e    -    -    -    -
```

How to get it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

> df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "var1",values_from = "var3") %>%
+   arrange(var2) %>% column_to_rownames("var2") %>% t()
```

gives

```
     tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4 tab5
tab1 NA   "a"  "f"  "g"  NA  
tab2 NA   NA   NA   "b"  NA  
tab3 NA   NA   NA   NA   "c" 
tab4 NA   NA   "d"  NA   NA  
tab5 "e"  NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Use `as.data.frame()` to convert it into a df, `as_tibble()` don't keep the row names. If you want NAs to be like "–", add `coalesce("–")`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very elegant base R solution, but it still does its job.

```
# create positions for final table
df$row <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", df$var1))
df$col <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", df$var2))

# create vector of tables (combining names from var1 and var2)
tables <- unique(c(df$var1, df$var2))

m <- matrix("-", nrow = length(tables), ncol = length(tables),
            dimnames = list(tables, tables))
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
  m[df$row[i], df$col[i]] <- df$var3[i]
```

Output

```
#      tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4 tab5
# tab1 "-"  "a"  "f"  "g"  "-" 
# tab2 "-"  "-"  "-"  "b"  "-" 
# tab3 "-"  "-"  "-"  "-"  "c" 
# tab4 "-"  "-"  "d"  "-"  "-" 
# tab5 "e"  "-"  "-"  "-"  "-"
```

Comment: Easy and simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
       df%>%
      spread(var2,var3,fill='-')
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?